# Python how to random pick a veriable with 3 values asigned to it?

Tags: python

Okay I will try to explain as easy as possiable, I want the player to random.randint between 1 to 3 and add the monster to the hand but im not sure how I would go about asigning a variable with 3 values the name,attack and defence, I have tried putting the variables into a list and random pick that but it errors out saying cant add veriable with more then 1 veriable.

```
    import random
    
    
    class Mon:
        def __init__(self, name, a, d):
            self.name, self.attack, self.defence = name, a, d
    
    
    player_hand = []
    # Monsters      Name   Attack Defence
    monster1 = Mon("geoff", 1000, 800)
    monster2 = Mon("Harry", 900, 1000)
    monster3 = Mon("Sophie", 1900, 1600)
    
    while True:
        try:
            player = int(input("Draw a card! :1"))
        except:
            print("You didnt pick a number")
            continue
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you show expected output? Or what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary, for example:

```
monster1 = {"name": "Geoff", "Attack": 1000, "Defence": 800}
monster2 = {"name": "Harry", "Attack": 900, "Defence": 1000}
monster3 = {"name": "Sophie", "Attack": 1900, "Defence": 1600}
```

In order to extract a value:

Eg. To extract monster1's attack:

```
print(monster1["attack"])
```

In order to randomize the monster, you can do:

```
def randomize_monster():
    print (random.choice(["monster1", "monster2", "monster3"]))
    
randomize_monster()
```

This randomizes between the 3 monsters and prints "monster1", "monster2" or "monster3".

Comment: this seems to be more close to what I want, so the last thing is how would I do a random.randint(1,3) so I can have the enamy have a random monster and the user a random monster

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but maybe it is this:

```py
mons = [monster1,monster2,monster3]

current_mon = random.choice(mons)
```

Now `current_mon` is a random monster from `monster1, monster2 or monster3`